# Is there "Continue" syntax in SPSS?

Tags: spss

Sometimes I run an SPSS script without stepping through or putting breaks into the script, and it still stops partway through, with the bottom right saying CONTINUE...

Is there a way to tell SPSS to continue using Syntax?

Comment: Can you post an example of the syntax you've been using that stops and where it stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like an unclosed bock or loop - a DO IF, LOOP, or other command that requires a matching END ....  If you are running the syntax from a syntax window, you might not have selected the entire loop.

Just submitting the rest of the block would continue execution.

Comment: I am using the python module SpssSyntaxDoc to run syntax that works when I run it from the syntax window instead of in Python. For some reason. I was hoping there was a syntactical way to tell the script to keep running...

Comment: I would recommend using the spss.Submit api rather than that method.  When you run from the scripting RunSyntax method, that syntax is queued to run after any pending syntax, but if the syntax you run is incomplete, it will remain pending until you submit the rest, but you can't do that, because something is still pending.  If for some reason you need to get the contents of the syntax window as the syntax to run, you can read it and then pass to Submit.

Comment: spss.Submit was the way to go! Thanks JKP.